# Advanced AlarmManager situation

Tags: java, android

I learnt about the alarmmanager and how "it can repeat the action daily at the same time". But I wanted to make alarm manager to repeat the "action" every WEEK or every MONTH or like the alarmmanager does the action every 15 secs or mins. I just can't find tutorial or even the right keyword for those.

IS there any tutroials/articles to teach this kind of AlarmManager action?

Comment: You set it the exact same way. Just use a longer interval.

Comment: Oh... right that might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setRepeating(..)` - which is described in detail [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

If you want to repeat the alarm in an interval that is not provided in the available constants just calculate the correct amount of milliseconds (e.g. for a week: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 (1 sec * 60 -> 1 min * 60 -> 1 hour * 24 -> 1 day * 7 -> 1 week)